# How to create cases as key value in PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, model-view-controller

I am facing some logical issue. I am fetching data via `upi status` table which look like as follows.

[image]

on controller file i am creating the following logic..

```
$this->load->model('localisation/upc_status');
  $statusArray =  $this->model_localisation_upc_status->getUPCStatuses();
  $this->data['statuses'] = $statusArray;

  foreach ($statusArray as $sa){
   $c[] = array($sa['status_id'] => $sa['name']);
  }

  echo $c['8'];
```

i am unable to get the name `in-stock`. instead i am getting `Array` in-place of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

```
    $c[$sa['status_id']] =  $sa['name'];
```

If you still can't get, adjust levels of the array.
Use print_r(array) to check arrays at required debugging points.